# how do I make a chloropleth map zip code to column in folium

Tags: python, folium

I am trying to create a chloropleth by mapping zip codes to a cluster column on a data frame
playing with stuff I've found on the folium site and tutorials, but I am new to this library.

Using this currently as a tutorial: https://www.roelpeters.be/plot-choropleth-map-geopandas-folium/

I've created a geopandas json file from census zip code data, and get zip code outlines on my folium map, but the zip codes are not coloring to the cluster data. I end up with the entire map in grey, though I know there is data there (due to the locations of businesses and my starting gps coordinates from the iterrows[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/03l5K.png)

Any assistance on what steps I'm missing would be greatly appreciated. Do I need the cluster column in the geopandas file?

''''
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import folium
import geopandas as gpd

```
df = pd.read_excel('folliumsample.xlsx')

df.head()

#census shape file from zip code data 2020 https://www.census.gov/geographies/mapping- 
files/time-series/geo/cartographic-boundary.2020.html ZIP Code Tabulation Areas (ZCTAs)
path = "cb_2020_us_zcta520_500k.shp"
geo = gpd.read_file(path)
geojson = geo.to_crs("EPSG:4326")

geojson.rename(columns={'GEOID20':'Zipcode'}, inplace=True) #rename 
zip code to same as my df
df['Zipcode']=df['Zipcode'].astype(int) #change to type int
geojson['Zipcode']=geojson['Zipcode'].astype(int)
df_merged = df.merge(geojson, on=['Zipcode']) #merge both 

df_merged.head()

geo = gpd.GeoSeries(df_merged.set_index('Zipcode') 
['geometry']).to_json() #convert to a json file


mymap = folium.Map(location=[39.6563, -104.7638],
           width = 950, 
           height = 550,
           zoom_start=12,
           tiles='openstreetmap')

folium.Choropleth(
geo_data = geo,
name = 'Choropleth',
data = df_merged,
columns = ['Zipcode','Cluster'],
key_on = 'feature.id',
fill_color = 'YlGnBu',
fill_opacity = 0.5,
line_opacity = 1,
legend_name = 'cluster data',
smooth_factor=  0
).add_to(mymap)

for index, location_info in df.iterrows():
    folium.Marker([location_info["Lat"], location_info["Long"]], 
              popup=location_info["Company_name"], #display 
 business name
              fill_color="#3db7e4" #color businesses
             ).add_to(mymap)''''
```

Sample data:

Company_name    Zipcode City    State   Lat Long    Cluster
0   Comp1   80013   Aurora  CO  39.6563 -104.7638   1
1   Comp2   80219   Denver  CO  39.6962 -105.0382   0
2   Comp3   80015   Aurora  CO  39.6288 -104.7813   2
3   Comp4   80134   Parker  CO  39.4626 -104.7754   3
4   Comp5   80634   Greeley CO  40.3963 -104.7871   1
5   Comp6   80016   Aurora  CO  39.5815 -104.7171   2
6   Comp7   80525   Fort Collins    CO  40.5418 -105.0441   1
7   Comp8   80631   Greeley CO  40.4398 -104.6821   3
8   Comp9   80229   Denver  CO  39.8581 -104.9564   1
9   Comp10  80504   Longmont    CO  40.1573 -105.0090   1

This is what my geofile looks like for properties:

'{"type": "FeatureCollection", "features": [{"id": "80013", "type": "Feature", "properties": {}, "geometry": {"type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [[[-104.81019612119022, 39.642137465196676], [-104.81014812414129, 39.64442046722674], [-104.81002113260413, 39.65098747304646], [-104.80995013541128, 39.65315147502026], [-104.80995914474724, 39.66050848125328], [-104.80995114870088, 39.663617483909924], [-104.80994615153455, 39.66584648581322], [-104.80993815539817, 39.66888548841048], [-104.80993315769658, 39.67069348995617], [-104.80992815958469, 39.672178491227456], [-104.80992716062626, 39.67299849192606], [-104.80992316292868, 39.67481049347325], [-104.80990417213638, 39.682057499667195], [-104.80759217310714, 39.68207750417318], [-104.8022311753691, 39.68213751463363], [-104.80106317585147, 39.68214251690581], [-104.79099417991726, 39.68210053642], [-104.790141180085, 39.68191953791836], [-104.78154718376396, 39.68208555474938], [-104.77236218749071, 39.682048572550094]

Edit: Added updates to the code. I merged the DF and the geo file, but still same issue. Everything that is fenced is black.

Answer (score 2):

The reason why it was not painted on the map correctly is that first of all both zip codes need to be strings, so I changed them to string format. Also, the association key is `feature.properties.Zipcode` in the case of a gdf file loaded by geopandas. I don't think there is a color fill for default markers, so I have disabled it. The attached image works with the sample data and is limited to the gdf (geojson) data.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import folium
import geopandas as gpd
import io

# df = pd.read_excel('folliumsample.xlsx')
# df.head()

data = '''
Company_name Zipcode City State Lat Long Cluster
0 Comp1 80013 Aurora CO 39.6563 -104.7638 1 
1 Comp2 80219 Denver CO 39.6962 -105.0382 0 
2 Comp3 80015 Aurora CO 39.6288 -104.7813 2 
3 Comp4 80134 Parker CO 39.4626 -104.7754 3 
4 Comp5 80634 Greeley CO 40.3963 -104.7871 1 
5 Comp6 80016 Aurora CO 39.5815 -104.7171 2 
6 Comp7 80525 "Fort Collins" CO 40.5418 -105.0441 1 
7 Comp8 80631 Greeley CO 40.4398 -104.6821 3 
8 Comp9 80229 Denver CO 39.8581 -104.9564 1 
9 Comp10 80504 Longmont CO 40.1573 -105.0090 1
'''

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), delim_whitespace=True)

#census shape file from zip code data 2020 https://www.census.gov/geographies/mapping- 
#files/time-series/geo/cartographic-boundary.2020.html ZIP Code Tabulation Areas (ZCTAs)
path = "/content/cb_2020_us_zcta520_500k.shp"
geo = gpd.read_file(path)
geojson = geo.to_crs("EPSG:4326")

geojson.rename(columns={'GEOID20':'Zipcode'}, inplace=True) #rename 
#zip code to same as my df
df['Zipcode']=df['Zipcode'].astype(str) #change to type int
geojson['Zipcode']=geojson['Zipcode'].astype(str)
df_merged = df.merge(geojson, on=['Zipcode']) #merge both 

df_merged.head()
# sample data sync
geojson = geojson[geojson['Zipcode'].isin(df['Zipcode'])]

mymap = folium.Map(location=[39.6563, -104.7638],
                   #width = 950,
                   #height = 550,
                   zoom_start=10,
                   tiles='openstreetmap')

folium.Choropleth(
    geo_data = geojson,
    name = 'Choropleth',
    data = df_merged,
    columns = ['Zipcode','Cluster'],
    key_on = 'feature.properties.Zipcode',
    fill_color = 'YlGnBu',
    fill_opacity = 0.5,
    line_opacity = 1,
    legend_name = 'cluster data',
    smooth_factor=  0
).add_to(mymap)

for index, location_info in df.iterrows():
    folium.Marker([location_info["Lat"], location_info["Long"]],
                  popup=location_info["Company_name"], #display business name
                  #fill_color="#3db7e4" #color businesses
             ).add_to(mymap)
mymap
```

[image]

I couldn't get the data at the URL in the question, so I got the data from the following [site](https://www2.census.gov/geo/tiger/GENZ2020/shp/).